# Close the current tab and open a new - works only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

This code is intended a open a new tab and close the current:

```
<a target="_blank" title="It'll be opened in the new tab." onclick="javascript:window.close();" href="123">My link</a>
```

It works in Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari it doesn't close close the current tab.

Comment: You could try delaying the `window.close()` using a `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is your using `onclick` and `href` on your `href` try putting

```html
onclick="location.href='Place URL Here'"
```

Keep in mind that google chrome is very lenient when it comes to coding you can have hundreds of warnings and errors and the possibility for everything to display properly firefox is very strict interpretation of W3C HTML5 standards so a fallback might be useful and safari does not comply with W3C standards apple just kinda does their own thing so coding for safari might be a little more challenging

OR
 Since you want the page to close and want another to open you could simply just put an `onclick` which will open in the current browser so basically like a redirect button

```html
//Hyperlink
<a href="URL Here">Value Here</a>
//Button
<input type=button onclick="location.href='URL Here'" value="Value Here">
```

Ethier one of these codings will work perfectly for what your trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't see the solution for "Close the current tab and open a new".

Comment: What hes doing is not even supported by a lot of web browers anymore cause targeting is now a CSS element so he should take the rest of that out and just use my siggested codes theres no need to close the tab when you could just redirect in the same tab

Comment: If I could redirect I'd not ask this question.

Comment: Perhaps i could help you more if i knew the actual purpose can you meet me on code.stypi.com and i can help you through this?

Comment: It's too long to explain, I need what I asked in my question.

Comment: Hmmm well a lot of the code your using will not work in firefox or safari because it does not comply with W3C standards...I will have to think abt this and get back to you on it